# How do I alert(); the result of this JS function?

Tags: javascript, object

I am doing the following exercise (while studying JS):

"Create a function `multiplyNumeric(obj)` that multiplies all numeric properties of obj by 2."

The solution is:

```
function multiplyNumeric(obj) {
  for (let key in obj) {
    if (typeof obj[key] == 'number') {
      obj[key] *= 2;
    }
  }
}
```

`multiplyNumeric` does not need to return anything, it should modify the object in-place.

But what if I want to alert it? I tried different solutions, but I can't get it right..is there a reason why it doesn't alert or I'm just doing it wrong?
(exercise reference here: https://javascript.info/object)

I tried:

```
    let obj = {
    first: 100,
    second: 200,
    third: "Hello"
    };

    function multiplyNumeric(obj) {
      for (let key in obj) {
        if (typeof obj[key] == 'number') {
         obj[key] *= 2;
        } 
      }
    }

 alert(obj);
```

In this case it alerts: `[object Object]`

I also tried `alert(obj.first);` but it alerts 100.
I tried to put the `alert(obj);` inside the curly braces but it does nothing.

Please be patient, I am just a beginner...

Comment: What have you tried? There is no `alert` in the code you provided.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `console.log()` as it will display objects nicely. However if you are determined to use `alert()` you should know that `alert()` only takes in strings. So try `alert(JSON.stringify(obj))`

Comment: While your suggestion is correct, the reason isn't. You can pass anything to an `alert` and, if it's not already a string, it will be coerced into one. In the case of Objects, that means that their `.toString()` method will be called. Typically, that method hasn't been overridden, so the output is `[object Object]` to indicate the type and what it inherits from.

Answer (score 1):

to alert each key in obj seperatly:

```
function multiplyNumeric(obj) {
      for (let key in obj) {
        if (typeof obj[key] == 'number') {
          obj[key] *= 2;
          alert(obj[key]);
        }
      }
    }
```

if you want to alert it together, after all the multiply finish, than

```
function multiplyNumeric(obj) {
      for (let key in obj) {
        if (typeof obj[key] == 'number') {
          obj[key] *= 2;
        }
      }
      alert(JSON.stringify(obj));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use console.log()
let obj = {
    first: 100,
    second: 200,
    third: "Hello"
    };

```
function multiplyNumeric(obj) {
  for (let key in obj) {
    if (typeof obj[key] == 'number') {
     obj[key] *= 2;
    } 
  }
}
```

Console.log(obj);

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any `alert()` in the question. Since, I don't have much reputation to comment, I am writing the code which works.

```js
function multiplyNumeric(obj) {
  for (let key in obj) {
    if (typeof obj[key] == 'number') {
      obj[key] *= 2;
    }
  }
}
var obj = {'number' : 2};
multiplyNumeric(obj);
alert(obj['number']);
```